Как задать траекторию летящему снаряду в Unity 2D
В моей игре есть оружие-бумеранг. Мне необходимо, чтобы после того, как бумеранг пролетит определённое расстояние, он разворачивался и летел в обратную сторону.
Скрипт самого снаряда:
public void Update()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

Скрипт пушки:
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
    {
        Instantiate(bullet, shotPoint.position, shotPoint.transform.rotation);
    }

(shotPoint - место, откуда вылетает пуля)
Мне нужно сделать, что снаряд, пролетев определённое расстояние (или через какое-то определённое время, не суть важно), развернулся, немного подлетев вверх, и полетел в обратную сторону. Вот пример того, что мне нужно, под цифрой 1:

Стрелять можно будет в восьми разных направлениях: север, юг, запад, восток, юз, юв, сз, св, и из любой точки - персонаж передвигается по всей карте, а не стреляет из фиксированного места.
Второй пример под номером 2. Мне нужно сделать, чтобы два снаряда, вылетающие из одного и того же места в один и тот же момент двигались волнами. Как задать такую необычную траекторию?

Тебе нужна логика перемещения по пути. В твоём случае, предположим, это миниум 3 точки - куда летим, смещение от конечной точки вверх, куда возвращаться. Эту логику нужно пихать не в апдейт, а в корутину, например, скормив ей массив этих точек. Или еще можешь взять какую-нибудь библиотеку, например  DG.Tweening - там уже есть метод перемещения объекта по пути.

Manciny, спасибо, я попробую!
